# Merge two file line by line using awk

Tags: awk, sed

I have got two files named file1.txt and file2.txt.

file1.txt :

```
Tom
Harry
Martin
job
Kevin
```

file2.txt :

```
Samson
Edward
Thomas
Wilco
```

Mergefiles.txt:

```
Tom
Harry
Martin
job
Kevin
Samson
Edward
Thomas
Wilco
```

I am using "cat" to merge these files but would like to know if this a good approach or can be done using awk command. pLease help.

```
cat file1.txt file2.txt > mergefiles.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cat` was created specifically for this purpose. It means to "concatenate" files and that appears to be the operation here, so that is a good approach.

---

You could get the same behavior with `awk` :

```
awk 1 file1.txt file2.txt > concatenatedfiles.txt
```

But there really is no point in doing that if `cat` can do the same thing...

Comment: Cat is the best approach, sed can also cat files `sed : file1.txt file2.txt > concatenatedfile.txt`.